# GUI to display mounted shares?

Tags: gnome, mount, cifs, extension

I have a media server with media stored on mounted CIFS share. I'm looking for an app like system-monitor-shell gnome shell extension which displays system resource status, but instead displays CIFS mounts. That way I can glance at it and know if any shares are not mounted.

Think the output of
`findmnt --list --types cifs`
but in a GUI.

Comment: Have you tried [Gigolo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/gigolo)?

Comment: No, I haven't heard of it before now. I'll see if it does what I want and mark your answer if it does. Hopefully its like Automounter for Mac which displays the status of mounted network shares.